# Connection with static IP does not autoconnect Lubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, lubuntu, network-manager

I'm tring to use the following configuration on Lubuntu 16.04 (that works on my VM that also runs Lubuntu 16.04). This is what `/etc/network/interfaces` looks like:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp3s0
iface enp3s0 inet static
address xxx.xxx.xxx.x
netmask 255.255.255.128
gateway xxx.xxx.xxx.x
dns-nameservers xxx.xxx.xxx.xx xxx.xxx.x.x
```

and this is what my `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` looks like:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=true
```

In this configuration when ever the system boots I get no Internet and 2 connections (`enp3s0 and Ifupdown(enp3s0)`) when I click on the NetworkManager task bar icon. When I choose `enp3s0` I get a dialog informing me that

*Connection activation failed (2)Active connection removed before it was initialized*

and `enp3s0` disappears and only `Ifupdown(enp3s0)` is left but with working internet. If I select `Ifupdown(enp3s0)` right away then i get no error dialog but `enp3s0` disappears as well.

If I omit the line `auto enp3s0` from `/etc/network/interfaces` after boot the network manager shows no connection and I have to manually select `Ifupdown(enp3s0)` from the connection menu.

I don't know that the problem could be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `interfaces` file suggests that you want that file to manage your connection. However, in Network Manager, the `managed=true` declaration suggests that you want NM to manage your connection. You have a conflict. There are too many hands on the steering wheel!

I recommend that you remove the enp3s0 settings from `/etc/network/interfaces` and set your static IP in Network Manager:

[image]

Comment: Thanks I will try it out as soon as I can. Just weird though that most guides I found suggest that setting `managed=true` means that I will take over the management from Network Manager.

Comment: My source is: `man NetworkManager.conf` where is says: *managed
           If set to true, then interfaces listed in /etc/network/interfaces are managed by NetworkManager.*