# Custom /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections file

Tags: network-manager

Ubuntu 16.04.1 is not generating a `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` file for `eno1` wired Ethernet. I wrote my own but need ipv4 with static IP address yet Ubuntu is using DHCP to assign an automatic IP address. Below is the file. See `method=manual`. Why is Ubuntu ignoring `method=manual` and instead assuming `method=auto`?
Also, cannot find any documentation describing syntax of `addresses` element of `ipv4`.

```
[connection]
id=eno1
uuid=4518f0a6-0500-4848-a849-85c0c6c389b6
type=802-3-ethernet
permissions=
secondaries=

[802-3-ethernet]
duplex=full
mac-address=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX

[ipv4]
method=manual
addresses1=192.168.10.251;24;192.168.10.1;

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
dns-search=
method=auto
```

Comment: Did you set the address in the GUI first? http://askubuntu.com/questions/881196/connection-with-static-ip-does-not-autoconnect-lubuntu-16-04/881244#881244

Comment: No, but I am ultimately dealing with a headless system, no keyboard, no display, no GUI. I now understand from your post that /etc/network/interfaces also needs to be edited. I have now edited interfaces for "iface eno1 inet static [newline] address 192.168.10.251 [newline] netmask 255.255.255.0 [newline] gateway 192.168.10.1 [newline] and now unfortunately "ifconfig -a" shows no IP address assignment for eno1, not even the DHCP address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running headless, without display or graphical desktop environment, please edit `/etc/network/interfaces` to something like:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eno1
iface eno1 inet static
address 192.168.10.251
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.10.1
dns-nameservers 192.168.10.1 8.8.8.8
```

Be sure to select a static address outside the range used by the DHCP server in the router, switch or other access point. Of course, substitute your details here.

Get the system to read and use the changes:

```
sudo ifdown eno1 && sudo ifup -v eno1
```

Did you connect?

```
ping -c3 192.168.10.1
ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com
```

Comment: chili, ++. Note that, on 16.04, restring `networking.service` would handle the `ifupdown` stuffs..

Comment: Success! My mistake, when I originally edited /etc/network/interfaces, was omitting the "auto eno1" though following with the "iface eno1 inet static...". Can ping remotely, many thanks!

Comment: Awesome! Glad it's working.