# Ubuntu 16.4 keeps dropping IP address that its been assigned by the network every week

Tags: 16.04, dhcp

So my network is assigning an IP address to my ubuntu box, and its fixed on the network it never changes. However, every week ubuntu keeps dropping the IP address and the box has to be restarted. 
How can I assign a static IP address within ubuntu?

Or is there a better solution?

I have all the info I need like the IP, Mask, DNS1, DNS2 and Gateway, I just dont know where to put it.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but check here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/881196/connection-with-static-ip-does-not-autoconnect-lubuntu-16-04/881244#881244

Comment: `/etc/network/interfaces`. [`man 5 interfaces`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man5/interfaces.5.html) is what you should read.